# Using google API gateway as single access point for app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iap, google-api-gateway

Recently I've implemented a couple of microservices on App engine, and I wanted to secure them through an **API gateway** (NO CLOUD ENDPOINTS) that authenticates every request before forwarding it to the backend. However, App Engines have a public address that can be called, bypassing the authentication mechanism provided by the API gateway. To avoid this behavior I tried to activate the IAP at the App engine level, however after that all the requests started to fail.

1. CORS PROBLEM: The request started to fail signaling that the CORS header was not included (the **backend, however, provides the header and the OPTION request is allowed in the API gateway**). After enabling options requests also on IAP, the OPTIONS preflight were delivered correctly, however post and get request continues to fail.

NOTICE: if I **DISABLE THE IAP** the requests are handled **correctly without any error**

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this? (This is not a code problem, but a GCP setup problem, so code is meaningless)

Comment: Can you provide the actuall API calls you're sending (please anonymize them first) and the API response ? Ideally you can provide steps for reproducing your issue.

Comment: The problem is not tightly related to the call itself: I even tried building a simple "\hello" API that answer "Hello world". I call without activating the IAP, everything works fine. The API gateway forward the call and hello world is retrieved. However, if I activate IAP, every call fails. I think I'm missing some process in the google cloud console, but I don't know what.